Automorphism of the torus that changes the homotopy type of a loop
Here's a fun breakfast problem which has pestered me for many a breakfast. Let $T^2 \cong S^1 \times S^1$ denote the torus. Say you have a noncontractible injective loop $\gamma: S^1 \to T^2$. Does there exist a self-homeomorphism of the torus $\varphi: T^2 \to T^2$ such that $\varphi \circ \gamma$ is contractible?
More generally, if $\gamma$ is homotopic to $(a,b) \in Z^2 \cong \pi_1(T^2)$ and $(c,d)$ is another element of the fundamental group of the torus, does there exist an automorphism of the torus making $\gamma$ homotopic to $(c,d)$?
Assume whatever basepoint requirements and equivalence relations are needed to make the problem make sense.

Homeomorphisms are weak homotopy equivalences and thus induce isomorphism of all homotopy groups, including the fundamental group. No group isomorphism can send a nonidentity element to the identity, so the answer to your question is no. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

For the question in the title, try $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$. For dealing with the general question, have you tried working in the universal covering space?

That is not an isomorphism, but an embedding. As @JonathanZ points out, the only nontrivial automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is the interchanging of coordinates. This is really a categorical automorphism of the direct product.

@Malady - Are you sure there isn't some 2x2 matrix of integers with det = 1 that gives an automorphism of $Z^2$, and thus induces a self homeomorphism of the torus?

@JonathanZ you are correct. My apologies.

@Malady - No worries, no apology needed.

Am I only allowed to think about this during breakfast?

No, this is not possible, for suppose that the map $\phi \circ \gamma : S^1 \to T^2$ is contractible. Let $H : S^1 \times [0,1] \to T^2$ be a contraction: $H(z,0)=\phi \circ \gamma(z)$ and the image of the restriction $H \mid S^1 \times \{1\}$ is a point $p$.
It follows that $\phi^{-1} \circ H$ : S^1 \times [0,1] \to T^2 is a contraction of $\gamma(z) = \phi^{-1} \circ (\phi \circ \gamma(z))$ and the image of $\phi^{-1} \circ H \mid S^1 \times \{1\}$ is a point $\phi^{-1}(p)$.
As for your more general question,  you can attack it using a basic property of the fundamental group: any self-homomorphism $\phi : T^2 \to T^2$ induces a self-isomorphism $\phi_* : \mathbb Z^2 \approx \pi_1(T_2) \to \pi_1(T_2) \approx \mathbb Z^2$.
This has the effect of translating your question into pure algebra, and this gives a second proof of your question based on pure algebra. Namely, given $g,h \in \mathbb Z^2$ does there exist a self-isomorphism $\Phi : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z^2$ such that $\phi(\gamma)=\delta$? If $g \ne (0,0)$ (equivalently, if $g$ is represented by a noncontractible loop in $T^2$) and if $h = (0,0)$ (equivalently  if $h$ is represented by a contractible loop in $T^2$) then the answer is clearly "no", just on the basis of algebra: a self-isomorphism always take the identity element of the group to itself. So there is a second proof, besides the topological proof that I gave first.
Finally, the question in your "More generally" paragraph has a similar algebraic translation: Given $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z^2$ and another $(c,d) \in \mathbb Z^2$, does there exist an automorphism of $\mathbb Z^2$ taking $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$? The answer is "no, not always", and the reason is that we have a completely concrete description of all automorphisms of $\mathbb Z^2$: namely they are precisely the linear maps defined by the $2 \times 2$ integer matrices of determinant $\pm 1$. I invite you to apply this description to find lots of your own counterexamples $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.
